# Wireless mouse works, but can't do drag'n'drop in 17.04

Tags: wireless, usb, mouse, lenovo, logitech

I use a Logitech wireless (USB) mouse M570 which works fine in Debian, Windows, Mint etc. Only in Ubuntu 17.04 (on a Lenovo Ideapad Laptop N581) everything works **except**, if I try to drag anything (or resize a window) it 'loses contact', just as if I stopped pressing the left mouse button.

I'm stumped, but maybe you have an idea...

EDIT: If I use any other mouse or the touchpad drag'n'drop works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure it's not just the drag and drop feature that's broken under ubuntu 17.04 and not the mouse?

i can't drag and drop addons to brackets or brackets-electron for example but drag and drop to drive works.

sometimes it doesn't have the visual showing you that it is about to do a drag and drop but its actually working.

could you describe your issue more. maybe screenshots or a clip?

Comment: Yes, it's only the drag'n'drop feature with the wireless mouse. If I use any other mouse drag'n'drop works perfectly. It does show the visual (e.g. when resizing a window) but that disappears whenever I move the mouse.

Comment: then it has to be a mechanical defect with the mouse maybe the precision (on whether the click is held down or not) is at unacceptable lows and the "drop" happens almost immediately. could you test the mouse under windows/debian again?

Comment: Thanks, but it still works perfectly in Debian, Windows, etc.

Comment: here's why what you're saying makes no sense to me : ubuntu's few extra libraries over debian can't possibly mess with mouse input. consider that debian = ubuntu 
do you see why this makes this problem too weird to be true? only thing left to consider is that you're fluking out every time you try it on ubuntu giving you the same false positive over and over again. I see no other possibility.

Comment: I see you are as stumped as I am. Yesterday I was trying to adjust a split window with the mouse (nemo + F3) and it wouldn't 'stick' on the dividing line, so I switched to the touchpad and it worked perfectly. Bye the way, I switched from Debian 8 to Ubuntu 17.04 and there are many differences, e.g. kernel  went from 3.xx to 4.10

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue, where I even couldn't drag and drop using my touch-pad. After some struggle the following worked for me:

- On the preferences window of the nautilus **uncheck** `Experimental (use the new views)`